# HTML DIV inner scroll

Tags: html, scroll

I need a DIV to have constant width, regardless showing the scroll bar.

This is what I have so far:

`<div style="overflow: auto; width:100%; height: 100px;">`

How should this be changed ?

Comment: What do you mean by "constant width" exactly - a pixel width? If so, why not simply give it one? Or do you want the div's width to be independent from the width that the scroll bar takes away?

Comment: the div width should not increase when the scroll bar is displayed

Answer (score 8):

The `overflow` style has a `scroll` property which does what you want. You may also want to split it out into `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to allow you to control the two scrollbars independantly:

```
div {
  width:100%;
  height:100%
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Change the x or y overflow to `none` or `auto` depending on what combination of scroll bars you need.

Answer (score 0):

To get a constant width, specify a pixel value:

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width:200px; height: 100px;">
```